# Getting NullReferenceException in unity using dreamlo scoreboards

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception

I am working on my first game and have encountered an issue using the dreamlo scoreboard asset. It is basically a simple leaderboard system working using only HTTP GET requests, and no PhP/SQL. You can read more about it here: [Dreamlo](http://dreamlo.com/)

Using the class coming with the asset, I am getting a NullReferenceException on this function:

```
public string[] ToStringArray()
{
    if (this.highScores == "") return null;


    string[] rows = this.highScores.Split(new char[] { '\n' }, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    return rows;
}
```

Note that my program runs fine, and leaderboards are shown, but as soon as it gets to this function I am spammed with 19 NullReferenceExceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn more about [NullReferenceException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it).

And try this line:

```
 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.highScores)) return null;
```